# Sustainsys using Salesforce as IdP for multiple communities

Tags: sustainsys-saml2

I am using Salesforce as an IdP for my MVC app. I have multiple communities in my Salesforce instance each with a different signOnUrl. How do I configure multiple communities to use the same Sustainsys Identity Provider?

I have tried using the same community link for the different communities, that gives a privileges error. I've tried setting multiple Identity provider nodes for the different community signOnUrls but it hasn't worked

```
<identityProviders>
      <add entityId="https://{Salesforce}" signOnUrl="https://{Salesforce}/{community1}/idp/login?app={appId}" allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="true" binding="HttpRedirect">
        <signingCertificate fileName="~/App_Data/{cert}.crt" />
      </add>
      <add entityId="https://{Salesforce}" signOnUrl="https://{Salesforce}/{community2}/idp/login?app={appId}" allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="true" binding="HttpRedirect">
        <signingCertificate fileName="~/App_Data/{cert}.crt" />
      </add>
    </identityProviders>
```

When I try adding multiple entity providers to the same server the error is The entry `https://{Salesforce}` has already been added.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer... instead of adding multiple identity providers with different signOnUrl parameters. You can add multiple signOnUrls in the same node.

```
<identityProviders>
      <add entityId="https://{Salesforce}" signOnUrl="https://{Salesforce}/{community1}/idp/login?app={appId}*;https://{Salesforce}/{community2}/idp/login?app={appId}*" allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="true" binding="HttpRedirect">
      <signingCertificate fileName="~/App_Data/{cert}.crt">
      </add>
</identityProviders>
```

Comment: Are you sure that this works? The code only has support for one URL for the signOnUrl.

Comment: I can confirm that this works. I have two different communities and two different users logged in to each community and the Claims authorize both users in both communities using the two signOnURLs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using owin or asp.net core, a better approach is probably to register one authentication scheme for each Salesforce community. This will make your application work as two virtual service providers to Salesforce, one for each community.

When registering the SAML2 middleware/handler twice, you need to ensure that each instans has a unique EntityId and a unique ModulePath.

Comment: When I upgrade the application to .NET core, I will look into using this strategy.